# "One another" or "one and other"

Tags: conjunctions, eggcorn

I thought this might have already been asked, but apparently not.  Is using the phrase "one another" considered equivalent to the phrase "one and other"?  Is one of the two considered right and the other wrong?  To give an example:

> - The two computers were situated relatively close to one and other.
> - The two computers were situated relatively close to one another.

Comment: "One and Other" as a phrase I only know from Antony Gormley's art project: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_%26_Other

Comment: I think your example is not a good one. Because, I would rather "...close to each other."

Comment: @Pierre W: depends on what is normal for you. For me, this is a perfectly good example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first, "one and other" sounds quite wrong to me.  If it's a construction that's in use, it's one I've never seen.

The second, "one another", is standard.

Comment: I am quite certain that if it is said, it is someone wrongly parsing "one another", much like when someone says "mute point" (instead of "moot point") or "I'd just assume stay home as go out" (instead of "just as soon").

Comment: Yes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn